# Querying .NET DataSet and ignore rows that contain NULL

Tags: c#, .net, database

I've written some code to read a column of data from a dataset called `AltIds`.  The values are nullable.  My code is written to find all the values in the column that are not null and write them to an array.

```
Guid[] altIds = myDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
  .Select(row => row.Field<Guid?>("AltId"))
  .Where(x => x.HasValue)
  .Select(x=>x.Value)
  .ToArray();
```

The code works, but it seems a bit complicated.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine. You could restructure it to eliminate one of the selects, but then you would repeat yourself with the row.

```
var altIds = myDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(row => row.Field<Guid?>("AltId").HasValue)
                 .Select(row => row.Field<Guid?>("AltId").Value)
                 .ToArray();
```

You could rewrite it in query expression syntax, but that's only less complicated *if* you find fluent syntax more so.

```
var altIds = (from row in myDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
             let x = row.Field<Guid?>("AltId")
             where x.HasValue
             select x.Value).ToArray();
```

Either way, it's six in one hand, half a dozen in the other. I find your code readable, and it passes the "does what it is supposed to" test, so I wouldn't worry about this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This is terribly nit picky, but the whitespace is inconsistent. Give this line some breathing space.

```
.Select(x=>x.Value)
```

In a larger sample of code, this kind of thing becomes hard to read.